# Exporting an Oracle schema ORA 1455

Tags: oracle

I am using a version of Oracle 18c, when exporting a schema with the exp function it throws me the error ora 1455 with certain indexes in only 10 tables of 2624 tables that I have, and identified that these tables have a self-increasing column so I assume that is why the error occurs, do you have any way to avoid this problem? I have searched the internet and they recommend using indexes = N constraints = N statistics = none, but I cannot use this because if I need indexes and constraints to be exported, also try changing the way of exporting using expdp of data pump and I export myself a .dmp file but when importing it on another computer it did not give me absolutely nothing.

[image: Using impdp]

Comment: `exp` is no more supported unless for upgrading from older releases (older than 10g).  `expdp` is the right tool: please detail parameters given to `expdp` , to`impdp`  and any error message.

Comment: I have my user tsi to which I assign RW permissions in the directory DATA_PUMP_DIR and the role of EXP_FULL_DATABASE, I execute the following command:
expdp tsi / password DIRECTORY = DATA_PUMP_DIR DUMPFILE = TSI.dmp SCHEMAS = hr
I go to another instance and generate the user in which I want to import the schema and assign RW permissions in the directory DATA_PUMP_DIR and the role of IMP_FULL_DATABASE and execute the command:
impdp userCreated / password DIRECTORY = DATA_PUMP_DIR DUMPFILE = TSI.dmp SCHEMAS = hr
I don't get any errors but when entering my created user I don't have any table

Answer (score 0):

The user running `impdp` is different from the user owning the imported objects.

By default the objects imported are created in the source schema which is here `hr`: you should find your objects owned by user `hr`.

If you want a different owner you should add to `impdp` parameters something like: `REMAP_SCHEMA=HR:NEWUSER`.

Comment: So I don't have to separately generate a schema where the data will be imported? the hr schema, in case this is not generated automatically?

Comment: In general import will create the schemas to be imported in the database (when you do a database or schema import). Yes you don't need to re-create them.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. I will try what you tell me and write to you.

Comment: I have already tried it and the objects still do not appear to me, the schema is not created :(

Comment: Are you using a container database with pluggable databases or a non-container database ? Anyway to continue you should post full ouptut of the import command including the normal output displayed and the commands you run with output to check the schema.

Comment: It is a container database with pluggable databases, I have run it again and it throws error 31655 and 39154, I have added the image to my question

Comment: OK. ORA-39154 is a privilege issue. Are you sure that user running the import has `IMP_FULL_DATABASE` role ? I have made a test with Oracle 18.3 with 1 schema into a new PBD: with`IMP_FULL_DATABASE` it has worked for me and it should work for you.

Comment: ORA-31655 could mean that export file has no object exported and as a consequence nothing to import.

Comment: My user is assigned that role to import, to export and used the expdp statement tablelassinindices / password @ orcl1 DIRECTORY = DATA_PUMP_DIR DUMPFILE = TSI.dmp SCHEMAS = TABLASSININDICES
if it is correct to export like this?

Comment: With `EXP_FULL_DATABASE` on source database: yes it is correct.

Comment: This is how I did it, I don't understand why it doesn't work for me :( my user is created in the sid orcl1, does it have to be in the pdb orclpdb1?

Comment: yes the users/schemas to be exported/imported must be created in the PDBs. But we know it's the case because you cannot create such user names in the CDB$ROOT where you can only create common users with name C##xxx.

Comment: So what do you suggest I do? :(

Comment: Sorry I see no more options. Just doublecheck that the user running the import has IMP_FULL_DATABASE role: connect to target PDB as user running the import and check that IMP_FULL_DATABASE is listed by `select * from session_roles`.